# Specifying exact percentage widths in relation to parent DIV in CSS

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a visual element using DIV elements and CSS which should display data in the format demonstrated below.

[-----50%-----|--25%--|--25%--]

When using the code and CSS I've specified below, my final element always spills onto the next line and the CSS percentage values I'm specifying don't seem to create the layout properly.

Could anybody suggest a better way to do this?

**My HTML**

```
<div class="visual-indicator-title">
All Items</div>
<div class="visual-indicator-holder">
<div class="vi-internal-element" style="width: 25%; background-color: #5E9BD1;">
    25%</div>
<div class="vi-internal-element" style="width: 25%; background-color: #AB884D;">
    25%</div>
<div class="vi-internal-element" style="width: 50%;">
    50%</div>
</div>
<div class="visual-legend">
<ul class="inline-block">
    <li>
        <div class="legend-blue">
        </div>
        Sales</li>
    <li><span class="legend-tan"></span>Processed</li>
    <li><span class="legend-grey"></span>Pending Processing</li>
</ul>
```

**My CSS**

```
.visual-indicator-title{
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#777777;
}
.visual-indicator-holder
{
width:100%;
background-color:#666666;
height:28px;
border-radius: 8px;
}
.visual-indicator-holder .vi-internal-element
{
font-size:11px;
text-align:center;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#777777;
border-radius: 6px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason this happens is that with `inline` or `inline-block`, white space in the element will affect the rendering (adds space). Here is your demo working with white space removed, no changes to the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/fZXnU/

Removing white space is not trivial though, so you'd be better off floating the elements (which triggers `display:block`). Working demo with plenty of white space: http://jsfiddle.net/fZXnU/1/

Answer (score 9):

You can use `float: left`, `position: relative`, and then define width in percentage as you are.

I modified your code to use float here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3kdP/.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the white-space between the `div`s then it works as intended.

http://jsfiddle.net/TeJuU/

---

EDIT: See this question:  [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

You can make `font-size: 0` on the parent element if you don't want to edit your html.

http://jsfiddle.net/TeJuU/1/

Answer (score 2):

All of those elements have margin and padding with them as well as the percentages creating rounding errors during calculation. So you need to make sure you set, or take into consideration, what margin is doing to this. For rounding errors, it's typical to let the percentages add up to something less than 100% but then add margin: auto to center the whole thing.

Comment: They actually don't have margins, it's a space issue when using `inline-block`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Almost all elements have margin by default.

Comment: Not really, check it in firebug or inspect element in chrome, no margin.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - I suggest you do the same. Note I did not say all elements do but most or many do, including the ul in this example but I did not look into the rest of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use my code.

```
.visual-indicator-title{
     font-size:12px;
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#777777;
}
 .visual-indicator-holder {
     width:100%;
     background-color:#666666;
     height:28px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     display: flex;
}
 .visual-indicator-holder .vi-internal-element {
     font-size:11px;
     text-align:center;
     color:#ffffff;
     background-color:#777777;
     border-radius: 6px;
     height: fit-content;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).